# Javascript: Function overwrite with passing arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Winston (Logger for nodejs).

In my script i call:

```
log.error("my error", {input: [1,2]});
```

console show me:

```
error: my error input=[1, 2]
```

**What i want to do: don' call at log.error(null)**

In some functions i dynamically call the log.error with a variable and dont know if the variable are NULL or have a value. If i call log.error(null) he write "error:" to the console.

I tried with this:

```
log.error = (function () {
    var old = log.error;

    return function newerror() {
        if (arguments.length !== 0) {
            old(arguments);
        }
    };
})();
```

But now i got:

```
error: 0=my error, input=[1, 2]
```

as output.

**My Question**

how i can call the log.error() function with die arguments given (arguments-var in javascript is a object).

Function style:

```
function foo(arg1,arg2,...)
```

I want something like:

```
foo.call(myargumentsobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

oh i got it:

```
old.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: Please explain a bit this code line and add a link to corresponding documentation.